# Migrating from VS6 to VS2017 and having issues with the lib HtmlHelp.lib

Tags: visual-c++

This is my first question on this forum, so please forgive me if I do not get it right ;)

I am migrating an old MFC project from VS6 to VS2017, and am having issues linking to the previous HtmlHelp.lib file created via MakeHelp.bat.  I assume I need to generate a new one, or replace it with whatever came after, but I am not knowledgeable enough of VS to know what that is.  I am also assuming that because I am trying to link a file created with VS6 into a new project compiled in VS2017 that maybe there is some "name mangling" issues due to the difference in compiler versions.

I am getting the following link errors:

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: void **thiscall XXX::HtmlHelpA(struct HWND** *,class ATL::CStringT<char,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<char,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT > > const &,int,int)" (?HtmlHelpA@XXX@@IAEXPAUHWND__@@ABV?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@DV?$ChTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@@@ATL@@HH@Z) referenced in function "protected: void __thiscall XXX::OnHelp(void)" (?OnHelp@XXX@@IAEXXZ)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Jumping from VC6 (wow!) to VS2017 is a kind long jump... personally I'd migrate from VC6 to VS2003 first (in a VM, perhaps).

Comment: I don't believe linker files are portable between different versions of VS, btw.

Comment: This is your own function, not the one from htmlhelp.lib.  Note the XXX class or namespace.  We can't find it back for you, but do note that it got the A appended, a common macro mishap.  If that's the cause then fix with `#undef HtmlHelp`.